# ERROR. Emulador Android Estudio 3.6.1

Tags: android-studio

He conectado mi aplicación a una base de datos MySql alojada en un cloud server de Google y tengo los siguientes errores en el Event Log.

Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\Claudio.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.

Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554

Alguien me podría ayudar con esto por favor? No encuentro soluciones a este problema especifico en ningún lado.

Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solucione el error gracias a esto.
Desde el menú principal de la barra de navegación Herramientas> Android> SDK Manager> Android SDK> Herramientas SDK

Luego verá la pantalla a continuación donde puede seleccionar '- Controlador de hipervisor de emulador de Android para procesadores AMD (instalador) versión 1.3.0'
No estoy seguro de cuál es la causa raíz real del problema, pero esto me solucionó el problema y puede ayudar a otras personas.

Gracias a @Colin Gell